Vercel Next.js app pages not indexed by Google
I built an app using Next.js, but already one month past, all pages were not indexed by Google. I tried to add sitemap and robots.txt, now they can crawl but can not be indexed by Google.
Most of pages issue is excluded by a noindex tag. I checked the whole code, there is no this tag I added in this app. Anyone help can point what is the issue?


Please use this tag Next.js Application
''
Sitemap resubmission and re-indexing for Google crawl as per Google Search Console

are you generating your metadata for desired pages?

Please follow Here’s an easy step-by-step solution to fix the issue:
First Verify whether there is Actually noindex (or similar) metatag in your webpages
Please Open Google Search Console Dashboard then check settings -> Crawling -> robots.txt Valid
Incorrect Meta tag:
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">

Correct Meta tag:
<meta name="robots" content="NOODP" />

Please make sure to examine Your level of robots. txt if showing Disallow: / kindly follow below code
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Sitemap: https://stackoverflow.com/sitemap.xml // this is a dummy url

Make sure your application is properly working and crawl-able like Google's Mobile-Friendly Test to check it.
Please test if your site is working fine:
Google Page Speed Test
Sitemap resubmission and re-indexing for the affected pages will be necessary.
If you still can’t find a solution to your problem, please contact Vercel support or file an issue under the Next.js GitHub repo including all logs.

our robots.txt shown as below, there is no any meta tag shown on robots.txt.
Block all crawlers from accessing the /accounts directory
User-agent: *
Disallow: /accounts
Allow all other content
User-agent: *
Allow: /
sitemap:https://www.newsinoenergy.com/sitemap

@YanZhang I have checked your website, and all SEO checklists form Meta to sitemap.xml for Next.Js SEO make sure you follow all JS rendering logic so you can follow the official website

Please follow these NextJs official website Crawling and Indexing SEO rules:- https://nextjs.org/learn-pages-router/seo/crawling-and-indexing
